# Clone using jQuery not increment properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on clone Using jQuery. With my current code If the user click the addmore button cloning was working fine with id and name. The generating id was wrong it was initial id was cloned, duplicate id cloned1, cloned12,cloned123. But I want Cloned, Cloned1, Cloned2, Cloned3 etc.,,, And My second issue was if i click addmore button the clone one was not coming down it was going on the top (arranging clone issue)

Kindly please help me any solution please

Here is the jquery code

```
    //dynamic row for Attachment Table
$(document).on("click", ".attch_add_button", function () {
        var i=$('.cloned-row4').length; 
        $(".cloned-row4:last").clone().insertAfter(".cloned-row4:last").attr({               
        'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
        'name': function(_, name) { return name + i }
        }).end().find('[id]').val('').attr({ 'id': function(_, id) { return id + i }               

    }); 
        if(i < $('.cloned-row4').length){
            $(this).closest(".attch_add_button").removeClass('btn_more attch_add_button').addClass('btn_less');
        }
    i++; 
    return false;           
});
$(document).on('click', ".btn_less", function (){
    var len = $('.cloned-row4').length;
    if(len>1){
        $(this).closest(".btn_less").parent().parent().parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/546udj15/)

Kindly please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing a concatenation of string with int which gives a string result. The result of "1" + 1 is "11", not 2 !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the numbers from the end before adding your new number. Like this:

```
        'id': function (_, id) {
            return id.replace(/\d+$/, '') + i
        },
            'name': function (_, name) {
            return name.replace(/\d+$/, '') + i
        }
```

You will also want to make sure that if someone deletes a clone... you don't duplicate ids (if there were 10 clones, there would be a clone with an id of 9.. if someone deletes one and creates a new one, there would be another with an id of 9.) This could be fixed by getting the highest ID first... like this

```
    var i = 0;
    $('.cloned-row4').each( function() {
        var match = this.id.match(/\d+$/);
        var num = match ? Number.parseInt(match[0]) : 0;
        if(i < num+1) {
            i = num+1;   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to get the `clonedx` value, do manipulation and then change it into a different value? If you know the pattern is going to be "ClonedX" can't you directly use it? Then the easiest way would be

```
    'id': "cloned" + i,
    'name': "cloned" + i
```

Answer (score 0):

You only invoke one function when user clicked add more button.

```
  function setCustomAttr(){ 
        $('.cloned-row4').each(function(i,v){ 
            $(this).attr('id','cloned'+i); 
            $(this).attr('name','cloned'+i);
        }); 
    }
```